# Using attr on elements created with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I create a new DOM element with Javascript `document.createElement`, is there a way to use jquery function attr() to change the element's attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var element = document.createElement(tagName);
$(element).attr('foo', 'bar');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use javascript like :

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('href', 'mypage.htm');
```

or jquery

```
$(link).attr('href', 'mypage.htm');
```

Comment: (for the first method) if you will add an event (like onclick). maybe you should just use
link.onclick instead of link.setAttribute
source = http://justinfrench.com/notebook/javascript-setattribute-vs-ie

Comment: @yilmazhuseyin: Yeah, that's why I always recommend to use [DOM properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-642250288) over `setAttribute`.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can, but compare:

```
var element = document.createElement('input');

$(element).attr('type', 'button');

// vs.

element.type = 'button';
```

IMO I would simply use the second approach, staying away from the IE's buggy `element.setAttribute` method.